# Subsetting a matrix in R using array of locations?

Tags: r, matrix, subset

In R, I would like to subset a matrix by using an array that contains locations.  For example, if I had this matrix

```
mymatrix <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
```

I would like to be able to return an array that has the values found in columns

```
mycols <- c(2,3,2)
```

But `mymatrix[,mycols]`
returns a `3x3` matrix and not the result I would like, namely

```
c(2,6,8)
```

Google and "subset" don't seem to be helping me.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thx,
mconsidine

Comment: Yes, this answers the question.  I had not seen the answer you linked to before this, nor the one *it* links to, both of which are answers.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a row/column indexing by `cbind`ing with row sequence

```
mymatrix[cbind(seq_len(nrow(mymatrix)), mycols)]
[1] 2 6 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option using `mapply` + `asplit`

```
> mapply(`[`, asplit(mymatrix, 1), mycols)
[1] 2 6 8
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `mapply` in this way:

```
myrows <- 1:nrow(mymatrix)
mycols <- c(2,3,2)

mapply(function(i, j) mymatrix[i,j], myrows, mycols)
[1] 2 6 8
```